# how to extract text from table image using pytesseract and CV2?

Tags: python, tesseract, opencv, python-tesseract, text-extraction

I have a folder of images and the images are the same in format. I have tried the normal using pytesseract but it did not help me that much, I want to try cv2 library but I am very new at this, I tried various snippets over the internet but it did not help me but I think it can be done but I am not sure how.

[image: All images are in the same format]

I tried very simple code

```
import pytesseract
import cv2

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "path\to\tesseract.exe"

data = pytesseract.image_to_string('path\to\iamge',config=r'-l eng --psm 1')
```

```
Se

® @¢e8#8e8e8e0e¢@0@@ti@mhtC<CreméC<C“i we |e hUrUKhUCUC OhlhlUC HhC<C PC‘ SeCOUsehlU lhl

es =f eS &

 

,
ty
L
i
,

Se ent

js
uy
}
es
ed
O
2

F
O
fh
es
GQ

K
0

OO

oil
C

el

GNOQ-
POE
GNO—

ry
o

a
o-

OBC

GNO-

C

.

o

Blows cs
5.
FOBCC
Ee
ooscc

ohO=
OBC
Bid
3BCC
OG
HO8CC
NO
OBE

C
co
is
C

 

fant gu Leet
ent oe fend
6 ar
ifs Ba
i} be

“WORE | COO

Taods
Ry,
wd L
a
&

a
ae

tell
ee

i
Cpecoses

CCOs1
8
a
CCOS1
2
Cees,
o
CCcosi
af

i.

2
Le
od
5

BHO TB 38
Gl
12

ce
GCOS
i

8
g
Ey
oy
é
£3
ao
a
F
i

ah

 

0)
©
be
ee
ta
28
t Fy
Ae
bs
i

need
od
xmcowed
Hod,
PO SOe
5
i
a)
ot
ai
oS
a
Foiaé4
3
1
wh

4
4
a

Es

00m, S0e

L
0643
0
F3lOé44
O
FSLO&45
PILOG4S
Oo

as
é
5

 

|
\

Pe sos lig, sae
wa > :

fs fe
I
3

&
Pil

ot site emake

ov? Of} Ee
ans

   

 

 

 
 

  

, BONA. AA. QAM. ae, 2
i

| Sodoh BA | Doo BH

, DOCH
ch
£ERES

“a
oe
i

 

ie ni ae pee
Mee, Si, Moe
a es cy
ae on a w §

co bet Fg ee o Ra

a Bo mm G3 Saal fe

Oo
fy
uu

ft
LP

OsI03 BY

vat

os ont pa oo
ge tend tH «fn

is
: +
a ivi
ond rrt

"sot Pret E

ed
a

i¢
Fy
f

PSS ng BL ES
2

 

tr:
ee) iit Lees

—-

a
sy,
—

BEES

z
co
ny ge
?
f

 
 

 

g>
©o

 

o F
my
5.

iy
{3

 
 

lA
A,
1
H
as
ame
Li

=
C3 mo mo

Oo
6
0

eS) 3 2

td mo FW

Bx
D. DID. BO,

paey

 
 
 

to
MO
OQ

fo “dF £3 ds

i Pa 2 a

Ou
ay
?
é
wey
?
oor
Ee
Need
Pep om

ORG
a
af Le
aS

 

Mis
=|
a
4
%
web
Bes 3
‘eo
Bsa
tod
ms
a

p
ATT
eodd
pstry

E
i 5
Bae
sp
|

 

eet:

es cet ch cr
mo : bas

Rue fee
itd

oe 6 a BL

SLEOI

Ps
Te
x
are

 

my y
Gd
oy
asd

neh
ot Saocs
rs
3
wed
i}
ie
yet ms
eee

any

a

3
ted tet
wo

 

aay
Rt
Ps
wok
2
ee
fi
ES
Tacd

St
él

i
4

i
“|

é
THE
GIHOz
i,

t

50
D. Ia. BO
i
fy LH
i
S1LHO]
f
Hoe
i
SLHO
O38

z
¢
:
hd
a
i
mys

:
vt

isan
oy

LS
eee

 

“=
é
oop ony
eo
ein

Pn
o3
f
4 jt
a
}
“
Oa?
vi
ad ex

¢ ‘oon’ oy
iH De as

:
Ras
:
i;
=
ut

 

a
a

wed

at
co

we
wok
3
mo

=
am
co
i
Mas
3
bee

# if} mm &

foots poe bet eL

ness
Ay
1 KOO!
MAO
é
A
k
i
£
:

wt i

i
‘

 

OCi3
t
¢
i
+
i
my
‘at
og

 

4

ns
04
4
i

at ene as

=

 

2
ua
i
is
5 oa
a
ey

ad
a
‘$
3
24
oar)
ao
4

 

rr
i
Ki
K

Bed wa

sae | ts

She
2
¢
.
£3

aed
S
A
3

nd Ee

5
ie

iL
fi
i

 

Ver ed al.
acne
aod
pease
tn
—
=.

 
 

us

4

:

it

F a

ay 4

 

  

rah |
=)
o5
Hs
&
:
ES

Bo
we
os
te

®)
Eyees 2

DD. TWD. C80
t

=
ae) a s)
bed “Aen!
ay oe m3

AQIS
O
wAQSS
0
KOSO
“AORD
Kode
O3
KO
0 tes
HOKOSe
OS

fe}

end
fee
ay
Hi
end

wok £5

 

 

fre
Se

oo 2 int

tO
©)

1
ag.
boy
a4

ta mts
fh fb mo
i)

fail

BSKO54 JOS
me

165
295
3D
O94
117
#15

O8
LBi
1g?

wt,
es0BNngo

O04
oe

3
34. OOF

wt

@
fx
oe

 

ry

G
Fr
F
is
F
|
a
F
a
F
F

“eL

B08

 

 

 

 

 

 

eee ¢e*eeeee¢#8#e#ee#2e?¢@e#88fe8#eeeeemUmUHhmUCOMmUCUCUrH Uh]
```

This is what I got. Can I make it more accurate in some way. Thanks. Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Marina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16588238) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68642480) saying "Please use this article: [https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/table-detection-and-text-extraction-5a2934f61caa](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/table-detection-and-text-extraction-5a2934f61caa) Just follow the instructions. They also have a code on github."